# PHP regex issue getting one string

Tags: php, regex

I have data like the following

```
4  #VS   7 J9 C9 D9 I9 Z0 W8 S6 H0 LHRLAX 1115 1435      346 0E
5  $UN7107 J4 C4 D4 S. Y4 H4 Q4 B4 LHRLAX 1115 1435   *  744 0E
```

To get the data, I have the following regex

```
\A(\d)+[^#$]*?\#(?'code1'\p{Lu}{2})\s*(?'code2'\d{1,4})\b\s*(?<seat1>[A-Z][0-9.](?:\s+[A-Z][0-9.])*+)\s+(?<from>[A-Z]{3})(?<to>[A-Z]{3})\s+(?<other>.*\S)\s*
```

Now this works perfectly for the first line, but for the second line, the flight number starts with a $ instead of a # and I cant seem to match it.  I have added a $ to the regex string without success.

How can I get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\A` matches **start of string** while you apparently want to match **start of line** with `^`, and you also need to match both `#` and `$` while your `[^#$]*?` was only matching "anything until one of those characters":

```
^(\d)+\s*[#$](?'code1'\p{Lu}{2})\s*(?'code2'\d{1,4})\b\s*(?<seat1>[A-Z][0-9.](?:\s+[A-Z][0-9.])*+)\s+(?<from>[A-Z]{3})(?<to>[A-Z]{3})\s+(?<other>.*\S)\s*
```

[online test](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/aAF)